# Is there a way to show only applications visible on the current virtual desktop in the alt+tab list?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop, alt-tab

When I ALT+Tab in windows I'd like to scroll through the applications running in my current virtual desktop and omit the ones on my other virtual desktops.

Is there a setting, script, or application that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Multitasking under System in Settings, change the `Pressing Alt+Tab shows windows that are open` to `only the desktop I'm using`.

Comment: I actually have that option selected already but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Oops displayfusion was overwriting my settings. >.<

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 21H2, Multitasking settings, the option for Alt+Tab to work as requested is *Open Windows Only*, the other options in the dropdown all show a number of edge tabs.

Additionally, in those settings, there is a separate option for Virtual Desktops as shown:

[image]